# Do I need visa to be in Sydney Airport from 18,45 pm till 11,45 am? I am Argentinean

Tags: visas, australia, layovers, syd

I am Argentinian, travelling from Papua New Guinea to Argentina. I'll arrive to Sydney on the 19th of June at 18:55 pm and I am boarding my next flight on the 20th of June at 11:45 am. I am not going to leave the airport.

Comment: The airport technically closes overnight (it's not a 24 hour airport). So  I suspect you will have to leave, and therefore, get a visa. But I'm not certain so won't post as an answer

Answer (score 5):

According to https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/transit-facilities-at-australian-airports:

> #### Sydney (SYD), Cairns (CNS), Gold Coast (OOL)
>
> Do not operate on a 24 hour basis and overnight stays are not permitted. Passengers transiting overnight will need an appropriate visa for Australia to leave the airport to access overnight accommodation.

So you will have to leave the airport, and for this reason, you will need a transit visa (or a regular visitor visa).

Comment: Additionally, transit without visa is only allowed if less than 8 hours is spent in Australia, so even if it were possible to stay airside overnight, a visa would still be required. https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa

Comment: Reading the first link in your answer, it's kind of surprising that the largest airport in Australia doesn't operate on a 24-hour basis, while several smaller airports in Australia (presumably) do.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - "In 1995, the Australian Parliament passed the Sydney Airport Curfew Act 1995, which limits the operating hours of the airport. This was done in an effort to curb complaints about aircraft noise."

Comment: @LaconicDroid Not having any traffic (which is common in many, many large airports at night, for the same reasons) does not necessarily mean the international area should be completely closed and evacuated at night. Some airports like LHR close some terminals and will regroup all international transit passengers staying overnight in a smaller area for instance. But I suppose Sydney is not really a very common international transit point (other than NZ and a handful of smaller destinations, it's not quite the ideal routing).

Comment: @jcaron Overnight transit travellers at UK airports cannot avail of airside transit facilities, as stated in TIMATIC, and so need to fulfil the conditions at least for landside transit

Comment: @Crazydre Not sure what combination your entered in Timatic, but passengers can use a Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV) which does allow them to remain airside but not go through border control. This is applicable for transits of less than 24 hours, if the airport has overnight transit facilities.

Comment: @jcaron Nope, not 24 hours airside according to TIMATIC, but within the same calendar day. And yes, only available at all at Heathrow, Gatwick and Manchester. For landside transit, however, it's until 23:59 the following day

Comment: @Crazydre https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa "Your onward flight must be within 24 hours of your arrival in the UK." The rules Timatic describes are for TWOV, usually on the basis of having a visa for another "reliable" country such as US/CA/AU/NZ and travelling to/from there. In the case of DATV, the passenger would indeed have a UK visa (a quite specific visa which doesn't allow going through border control, but a visa nonetheless, and Timatic does not distinguish visa types, it just says "Visa required, except...").

Comment: @jcaron Ah, I get you! So airside TWOV is only allowed on the same day, while staying overnight is possible but requires a DATV. Kinda bizarre, but that's blessed I suppose.

Comment: @jcaron What about someone not normally requiring a DATV but not qualifying for landside TWOV (there are such cases), and wishing to transit airside overnight but for less than 24 hours? Are they eligible for a DATV or would they need a landside transit visa (even if seeking to remain airside)?